# Freezing on HP bios update?

Tags: motherboard, bios, updates, hp-pavilion

So, my computer (HP Pavilion g7) has been funky for the past few days and it eventually got to the point of when I turned it on, nothing would happen, only the lights would flash. I left it alone for a few hours and iI turned it on again and it did an HP BIOS update. The screen says:

"the system BIOS is being recovered
The recovery will take several minutes to complete 
Do not shut down or remove external power from your computer
Writing new BIOS image
Block 875/1057
Progress 82%"

Its been seemingly stuck at 82% for the last half hour. Should I leave it or restart it?

Comment: You should leave it the BIOS is already corrupt if the backup gets corrupt your up a dirt road without a paddle

Comment: A half hour isn't very long, let it do its thing or you risk bricking your mobo.